# jQuery submit ajax form with 2 submit buttons

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im trying to achieve the following, in php i have a form like this:

```
<form method="post"  id="form_1" action="php.php">
<input type="submit" value="add" name="sub"/>
<input type="submit" value="envoi" name="sub"/>
</form>
```

the form action file is:

```
<?php

if( $_POST["sub"]=="add"){  ?>

 <script>
 alert("")
 </script>
<?php  echo "ZZZZZZ";   ?>

<?php } ?>
```

so this means if i press sub with value add an alert prompt will come up, how can i do the same thing(differentiate both submit) but using a Ajax request:

the following code so does not work:

```
 $(function(){
      $('form#form_1').submit(function(){
var _data= $(this).serialize()
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php.php?",
        data:_data,
        success: function(html){
         $('div#1').html(html)

          }
     })
})
  })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="1" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;border: 1px solid red"></div>

<form method="post"  id="form_1" action="javascript:;">
<input type="submit" value="add" name="sub"/>
<input type="submit" value="envoi" name="sub"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You are missing semi-colons(`;`) in your javascript.

Comment: semi colons are not mandatory in Js, thats not the problem.

Comment: What *is* it doing, is your only problem that it's still doing a full postback?

Comment: i can't differentiate both submit buttons using Ajax form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the event handler on the buttons instead of on the form. Get the parameters from the form, and then add a parameter for the button, and post the form. Make sure the handler returns "false".

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=sub]').click(function(){
    var _data= $('#form_1').serialize() + '&sub=' + $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "php.php?",
      data:_data,
      success: function(html){
         $('div#1').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

You have to explicitly add the "sub" parameter because jQuery doesn't include those when you call "serialize()".

Answer (score 2):

In this case you need to manually add the submit button to the posted data, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('form#form_1 :submit').submit(function(){
    var _data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray(); //serialize form
    _data.push({ name : this.name, value: this.value });  //add this name/value
    _data = $.param(_data);                               //convert to string
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "php.php?",
      data: _data,
      success: function(html){
        $('div#1').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false; //prevent default submit
  });
});
```

We're using [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to get a serialized version of the form ([which is what `.serialize()` uses internally](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L84)), adding our name/value pair to that array *before* it gets serialized to a string via [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

The last addition is a `return false` to prevent the *default* submit behavior which would leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of semicolon missing, see below

```
 $(function(){
      $('form#form_1').submit(function(){
         var _data= $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "php.php?",
            data:_data,
            success: function(html){
               $('div#1').html(html);    
            }
         });
      });
  });
```

Comment: god i wanted to put -1 for your answer. Now it's ok back to 0.

Comment: It might not be ur answer, but its a good standard to follow , why dont u put -1 on that

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) provide some advance functionalities and it has automated some tasks which we have to do manually, please have a look at it. Also it provides better way of handling form elements, serialization and you can plug pre processing functions before submitting the form.