# form submit buttons referenced by "different" ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have two submit buttons in html "form":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
<form id="form1" action="" method ="post">
<input type="submit" value="check data" id="checkdata" name="checkdata" /><p>
<input type="submit" value="download" id="download" name="download" /><p>
```

which I have to get the query results of the button clicks from two separate "php" codes in the "same page" by ajax call. I have the script for the first button but I have trouble to assign the query for the second button which has to be referred to another php code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkdata").click(function(){
        var field1 = $("#field1").val();
        var field2 = $("#field2").val();
            var datastr ='&field1=' + field1 + '&field2=' + field2;
            $("#response").css("display", "block");
            $("#response").html("setting parameters... ");
            $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
            setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
        return false;
    });
});
function send(datastr){
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "some_php_code.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#response").html(html);
        setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',2000);
    }
    });
}
```

could you please give me some hint on this or is there any other method to do that?

(I have checked all the relevant questions that you might refer me to.
like this question which is related to only one ajax call 
[jQuery submit ajax form with 2 submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275640/jquery-submit-ajax-form-with-2-submit-buttons))

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: I don't see where you attempt to set up a click handler for the button with id of `download`.  You have one for the `checkdata` button, so it would be something similar, I would imagine.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes that was right.. I wouldn't think of anything of that Now it works.. You're the best man!

Comment: @MrOBrian  you're right by that but later it's going to be complicated

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").click(function(){
        var field1 = $("#field1").val();
        var field2 = $("#field2").val();
            var datastr ='&field1=' + field1 + '&field2=' + field2;
            $("#response").css("display", "block");
            $("#response").html("setting parameters... ");
            $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
            setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or better:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkdata").click(function(){
            SendData();
        });
        $("#download").click(function(){
            SendData();
        });
    });



function SendData() {

    var field1 = $("#field1").val();
    var field2 = $("#field2").val();
    var datastr ='&field1=' + field1 + '&field2=' + field2;
    $("#response").css("display", "block");
    $("#response").html("setting parameters... ");
    $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
    return false
}
```

hth